# How to make this code pick a random number each call Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
#randomly picks a monster for a random encounter        
class RanMob:
    #randint(1,2)
    roll=Dice.die(2)
    if roll ==1:
        mob=Goblin(Goblin.name,Goblin.hp,Goblin.thaco,Goblin.ac,Goblin.inventory)
    if roll ==2:
        mob=Orc(Orc.name,Orc.hp,Orc.thaco,Orc.ac,Orc.inventory)

while True:
    #pick a new random monster
    RanMob()
    #print the name of the random monster
    print(RanMob.mob.name)
```

When I run this code the `RanMob` class picks a new random number the first time through and then never picks a new number. How do I get it to pick a new mob each time I call `RanMob` in the main game loop?

Comment: unrelated: you should define default parameters for `__init__()` (or `__new__()` if immutable) methods so that you could write `mob = Goblin() if Dice.die(2) < 2 else Orc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a class. A class body is executed just the once (when Python encounters the `class` statement). The `RanMob()` line is entirely redundant here, it is not that line that executed the `Dice.die()` call.

Use a *function* and return the result:

```
def ranmob():
    #randint(1,2)
    roll=Dice.die(2)
    if roll ==1:
        return Goblin(Goblin.name,Goblin.hp,Goblin.thaco,Goblin.ac,Goblin.inventory)
    if roll ==2:
        return Orc(Orc.name,Orc.hp,Orc.thaco,Orc.ac,Orc.inventory)

while True:
    #pick a new random monster
    mob = ranmob()
    #print the name of the random monster
    print(mob.name)
```